# How to add a barcode to a flow document for printing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a program that reads in a serial number and then prints out a piece of paper with a generated barcode representing the serial number at the top, and a few paragraphs of text underneath it. But I have no idea how to get an image into the flow document.

I've managed to get everything besides the barcode to work. Right now, my code successfully reads in the number and prints out a paper with text only, but I'm stuck on how to get the barcode into the flow document.

I'm using https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib to generate the barcode image.

Here is what I have so far

```
FlowDocument fDoc = new FlowDocument();
fDoc.PagePadding = new Thickness(50);


Barcode b = new Barcode();
var img = b.Encode(BarcodeStandard.Type.Ean13, serialNum, 290, 120);

//not sure how to add that SKImage into the flow document        
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.FontSize = 12;
p.Inlines.Add(labelText);
fDoc.Blocks.Add(p);
```

Comment: Please share the code you have written thus far for us to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BarcodLib` generates images using `System.Drawing`, which cannot be directly used in `WPF`.
To display images in `FlowDocument`, you can use the `System.Windows.Controls.Image` element, which inherits from `FrameworkElement` (based `UIElement`).
Here, we can use `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` as the `ImageSource` for the `Image` element.

```csharp
var serialNum = "978020137962";

var b = new Barcode();
b.IncludeLabel = true; // add human readable label
b.Encode(BarcodeStandard.Type.Ean13, serialNum); // encode serial number

// use the GetImageData() method or the EncodedImageBytes property
// to retrieve the image byte array
byte[] imageData = b.GetImageData(SaveTypes.Png);
var ms = new MemoryStream(imageData /* b.EncodedImageBytes */);

// create a BitmapImage object as ImageSource for Image element
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
bitmap.EndInit();

Image elImage = new Image
{
    Source = bitmap,
    Width = 290,
    Height = 120
};

Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.FontSize = 12;
p.Inlines.Add(elImage); // add to FlowDocument
fDoc.Blocks.Add(p);
```

Comment: Looking into the source code of BarcodeLib, it seems more efficient to use the SaveImage method overload with Stream argument, instead of GetImageData. You could save directly into the MemoryStream that is used for the BitmapImage.

Comment: It is also not strictly required for MemoryStream, but good habit to dispose of every IDisposable. Wrap the MemoryStream in a `using` statement and set `bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`